Are there festivals to Rig Vedic Gods that lost prominence in the Itihasapuranas that are still celebrated today like the Indra Jatra in Nepal?
the Indra Jatra festival is observed in Kathmandu by Buddhists and Hindus.
https://www.footprintadventure.com/blog/biggest-jatra-of-nepal-indra-jatra

Indra Jatra, also known as Yenya Punhi, is the biggest jatra in Nepal, and it is celebrated with great zeal and enthusiasm in the Kathmandu Valley. Lasting for eight days, Indra Jatra is celebrated to thank Lord Indra (a Hindu deity) for bringing the monsoon rains that make cultivation possible. Rooted in ancient myth, Indra Jatra is celebrated by both Hindus and Buddhists with particular significance in Kathmandu Valley.

Are there festivals observed anywhere for deities like Varuna, Soma, Ashwins et al?

Sakrotthana is a festival dedicated to Indra which is historically observed in western Bengal on Indradvadashi. This ceremony was usually performed by the local Hindu feudatories-turned zamindars to secure their power & served as a means of displaying wealth. However, with decline in power & prestige of the zamindars under Communist rule, this festival has now been mostly  taken over by adivasis.

you can write it as an answer. @অনু

Bengali nibandhakāras Jīmūtavāhana & Raghunandana speak of the festival of Sakrotthāna being performed on Bhādra śuklā dvādaśī. In the Kālikāpurāṇa, this festival is described to involve hoisting of a ceremonial banner consecrated to Indra & His ceremonial worship. This festival has been historically observed by the Bengali Hindu feudatories-turned zamindars of Rāṛh Bengal to secure their power (against their neighbors & the Muslim overlords). However, with the decline in power & prestige of these zamindars (especially after the Communist government of Bengal seized their excess lands & redistributed it to their landless peasant-tenants & vigorously championed grassroots democracy in rural areas during the 80s), the festival has been taken over mostly by the ādivāsis, who renamed it as Iṇd Parab (Iṇd being a corruption of Indra). Now it involves tribal priests venerating a tree stump adorned with a white umbrella as the symbolic representation of Indra. Similar modifications have also occurred to the Sakrotthāna celebrations of the undivided Goalpāṛa district & undivided Kāmarūpa district in Assam.
Raghunandana states that Yama is to be worshipped on Bhrātṛdvitīyā alongside his scribe Citragupta & sister Yamunā. However, due to lack of knowledge about the procedure of worshipping Yama, people have done away with the ritualistic part & observe only the non-ritualistic part (anointing the brothers' forehead with sandal, exchanging gifts & feasting) of the ceremony. However, in rural areas of Bengal, Yama is revered by unmarried girls in the feminine vrata of Yamapukura. [N.B Feminine vrata refers to a class of rituals observed by unmarried girls & married women only with the sole aim of securing conjugal bliss in Bengali Hindu society not found in scriptures & passed on orally from mother to daughter & from mother-in-law to daughter-in-law and are often observed without the mediation of brāhmaṇa priests.]
Śāntiratna (also known as Śāntīkamalākara) composed by Kamalākara Bhaṭṭa directs that Vaidika deities are to be propitiated for rites of pacification. Indra is invoked in pacification rites conducted in case a missing person whose funeral rites by proxy had been conducted reappears back alive. Yama is invoked in pacification rites conducted in the aftermath of damage to temples & icons (caused naturally or due to vandalism), whereas Agni is to be invoked in pacification rites conducted in the aftermath of outbreak of fires in temples (caused naturally or artificially).
The rites of dedicating tanks & wells as recorded by Raghunandana & Nilakaṇṭha Bhaṭṭa prominently involve worship of Varuṇa. Writing around the 1800s, Christian missionary William Ward has recorded that in Bengali Hindu society, special worship of Varuṇa would be organised during times of drought, with the aim of seeking rainfall.
